# How can i color part of item string in listView?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

For example if in a `listView` I have the item:

```
Hello world
```

Then I want that `Hello` will be in red and world in green

In the top of the form I did

```
listView1.OwnerDraw = true;
```

In the designer I created `listView` draw item event:

```
private void listView1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawListViewItemEventArgs e) {
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();
}
```

What should I do from here?
What I want to do is to add in `Red` color a word to each item from it's left side for example:

```
`Hello world`
```

So world `Hello world`

So the first world on the left will be in red on this part.
I want to add this to every item.

Answer (score 2):

One way to achieve it is through [ListBox.DrawItem Event](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.listbox.drawitem.aspx). You can customize rendering of your strings in `listbox` in this function.

Add a new handler for that event:

```
listBox1.DrawMode = DrawMode.OwnerDrawFixed;
listBox1.DrawItem += new System.Windows.Forms.DrawItemEventHandler(this.listBox1_DrawItem);
```

And do rendering of texts in `listbox`:

```
private void listBox1_DrawItem(object sender, DrawItemEventArgs e)
{
    e.DrawBackground();
    e.DrawFocusRectangle();

    var itemStr = listBox1.Items[e.Index].ToString();
    var strings = itemStr.Split(' '); // Here I split item text
    var bound = e.Bounds;

    foreach (var s in strings)
    {
        var strRenderLegnth = e.Graphics.MeasureString(s, new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10)).Width;

        e.Graphics.DrawString // Draw each substring with customized settings
        (
            s,
            new Font(FontFamily.GenericSansSerif, 10),
            new SolidBrush(Color.Red), // Use verius colors for each substring
            bound
        );

        bound = new Rectangle(e.Bounds.X + (int)strRenderLegnth, e.Bounds.Y, e.Bounds.Width, e.Bounds.Height);
    }
}
```

Comment: Make sure to not mix up listbox and listview in your post!